# Is there a better way to put parameters into api url?

Tags: c#, api

This is more a question than a problem but none the less i coudn't find the answer on the internet.
When i assemble my api url inside my code i do it like this :

code :  `getProductId(baseUrl + "products/" + productID + "?client_id=" + clientID);`

Url :  https://www.testAPI/products/product123?client_id=user1

this works, but i'm pretty sure this isn't the right way to do it.
For example if the user could input something other than a productID into the paramter this could screw up my call for example:
there is another call in this api /products/productID/inventory?client_id=...

this call gives back an entire other object and it would screw with my code if i try to Serialise it from the json.

I know it's possible to give the parameters through the body or with a post, but that's not my usecase. The api that's given me uses url parameters.

thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For constructing URLs, you should use the UriBuilder class.
You can find the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=netstandard-2.0

```
var builder = new UriBuilder();
builder.Host = "...";
builder.Path = "...";
builder.Query = "...";
```

However as your concern seems to be that someone might pass in invalid data to the query parameters, you should build a strongly typed wrapper method around your URL construction logic.

```
public Uri CreateGetProductByIdUri(Product product, Client client)
{
    // Use product.Id and client.id here to construct the URL with UriBuilder
}
```

Comment: "strongly typed" should be treated as "strictly typed", btw ;) there is no such thing as "strongly typed"

Comment: yeah... there are lots of discussions on the topic out there, but what are you showing  in your answer is "**strictly typed**" method definition in any way